# how to add additional variable to serialized form for POST

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am serializing a form and then sending it via ajax using POST. There is a field on the page that isn't inside of this form so it isn't included in the serialize. I however want to also send it. I tried this but it isn't picking up the extra variable:

```
data: $( "#profileForm" ).serialize() + {token: token},
```

Comment: `data: $( "#profileForm" ).serialize() + '&token=' + token`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize builds a url-string of key-value arguments.

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/
like: `single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1`

I would advise you to add your token (which should be no array or object) as key value to it

```
data: $( "#profileForm" ).serialize() + "&token="+ token
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method and add multiple additional data:

```
var oData = $('#profileForm').serializeArray();
oData.push({name: 'token', value: token});
...
data: oData,
...
```

I hope this helped you, regards!